# Accessing files above the web server document root folder

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-10.04

Reading elsewhere, I have come across the concept of placing files I don't want accessible to the public above my web root folder. Doing this on my local WAMP stack works without issue, but once transferring over to my VPS (running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS) the PHP scripts can only see files under the root directory.

VirtualHost setup for my subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
# Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
ServerAdmin #####@####.com
ServerName admin.########.com
ServerAlias www.admin.########.com

# Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php admin.php
DocumentRoot /srv/www/#######.com/public_html/admin/web_pages

<Directory /srv/www/#######.com/public_html/admin/web_pages>
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# Log file locations
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /srv/www/########.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /srv/www/########.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Log error given: File does not exist: /srv/www/#######.com/public_html/admin/web_pages/css, referer: http://www.admin.########.com/

(My css folder is above the web_pages folder, and is called via this path: ../css/####.css)

Is this an issue with my configuration settings, or am I attempting to do something I shouldn't be, and instead have everything I need under my web root? I would really like constants files and application logic not accessible, but css,html pages, and images are ok.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to grant public access to some folders above web root, you may use [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive:

```
Alias /css/ "/srv/www/#######.com/public_html/admin/css"
<Directory /srv/www/#######.com/public_html/admin/css>
# some configuration directives here   
</Directory>
```

After that, your css files will be accessible via new path (without `..`): `/css/####.css`

Don't forget to switch on `mod_alias` Apache module

Comment: Good to know! Is there any way, however, to give access to php scripts alone and not public access?

Comment: It seems I misunderstand you question. Do you want to use script above document root for inclusion? Or you want to call this scripts directly? what do you mean by "to give access to php scripts alone and not public access"? You say what all is ok with your css, html and images, but where they are placed, under or above document root?

Comment: In your error log example, error was occured because server dont't grant access above document root and when you call `../css/####.css` (/srv/www/#######.com/public_html/admin/css/####.css) you just call /css/####.css (/srv/www/#######.com/public_html/admin/css/####.css) and this file really not exists.

Comment: My apologies Mihail, I'm not sure what I had done wrong in my code but after having ran across some other problems and needing to reform my directory structure, my PHP scripts in the root domain can now access the ones above root, and I moved non-script files into the respective document roots. Any common files I needed I created a soft link from above root so my domains could access them. Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions!